# Matrix over a ring with given kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a (commutative, unital,) Noetherian ring and let $M$ be an $m\times n$ matrix over $R$.  The columns of $M$ span a submodule $\widetilde M$ of $R^m$, but in general $\widetilde M$ will not be free.  Define, as usual, the kernel of $M$ to be $\ker(M) = \{v \in R^n \mid Mv = 0\}$ and denote by $M^t$ the transpose of $M$.  The kernel is a submodule of $R^n$; it is therefore finitely generated and so $\ker(M) = \widetilde K$ for some matrix $K$ with $n$ rows.

> **Question:** Let $M$ be an $m\times n$ matrix over $R$ and let $\widetilde K = \ker(M^t)$. Can we show that $\ker(K^t) \subseteq \widetilde M$?

Remarks:

- Note that $K^t M = (M^t K)^t = 0$ so $\widetilde M \subseteq \ker(K^t)$.  The opposite inclusion mentioned in the question will give $\widetilde M = \ker(K^t)$, which is what I want, namely that the matrix $K^t$ has kernel spanned by the given matrix $M$.
- The proof above that $\widetilde M \subseteq \ker(K^t)$ only uses the fact that $\widetilde K \subseteq \ker(M^t)$, but we know more, namely that $\widetilde K = \ker(M^t)$.  I haven't been able to turn this extra knowledge into a proof though.
- When all the modules in play are free and all the matrices give *bases* for the modules (echelon forms over fields for example), then the result follows easily by counting dimensions.
- For what it's worth, I've tested the result for lots ($\sim 10^4$) of small random matrices over $R = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n$ composite with many small factors (e.g. $n = 6, 12, 15, 24, 30$) hoping to find a counterexample, but the result has always been verified.